# PDO where should i use bindValue in every data by user

Tags: php, pdo

In which cases should i use `bindValue`? For example i have got Email data given by user and before inserting it i check it with `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` should i put `bindValue` on email also or i have got a password hashed with password_hash?

Comment: Always bind your variables, even if you validate it beforehand. It prevents SQL injection, and also prevents any pesky quoting issues that could crop up if you don't bind them.

Comment: All cases. Passing a `filter_var()` check is certainly helpful, but it doesn't necessarily mean the string is clean.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks!

Comment: @aynber thanks for your advice!

Comment: just don't mess around with passwords though, `password_verify()` takes care of all that. It's not advisable to escape or sanitize passwords, especially when it comes to ones such as `123'\abc` being perfectly valid. In escaping those, it could rewrite it as `123\'\abc` in turn failing on `password_verify()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so i shouldn't do any validation check on password as long as i hash it?

Comment: well, validation on passwords does have its pros and cons; just be careful that you're not limiting them

Comment: If you use the same validation when creating the passwords it should workout, but filtering decreases entropy and as a result the security of the passwords.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what about `htmlspecialchars` on passwords?

Comment: no, don't use that, there's no need and could cause more harm than good. Just use `password_verify()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- okay,thanks

Comment: You're welcome Bruno, *cheers*